# Data is not loaded while using load command in cassandra using YCSB

Tags: cassandra, ycsb

I am not able to load and run my data in cassandra using ycsb while running ycsb on windows. 
I used command

```
python ycsb load cassandra-10 -P C:\Users\Faria\Desktop\Test\YCSB\workloads\workloada -s > load.log
```

But no data is loaded. 
Please provide me with solution

Comment: Please add error information to the question. Check looking into log helps

Comment: after using above command load file is created in log but it is showing missing property: workload

Comment: Missing property: workload
java -cp C:\ycsb\cassandra-binding\lib\cassandra-binding-0.1.4.jar;C:\ycsb\core\lib\core-0.1.4.jar;C:\ycsb\gemfire-binding\conf;C:\ycsb\hbase-binding\conf;C:\ycsb\infinispan-binding\conf;C:\ycsb\jdbc-binding\conf;C:\ycsb\nosqldb-binding\conf;C:\ycsb\voldemort-binding\conf com.yahoo.ycsb.Client -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.CassandraClient10 -P C:\ycsb\workloads\workloada -s -load

Answer (score 0):

In this command you are missing a property of record counts to be inserted and host property.
And one more thing is the port no.
by default cassandra connects to 9160 port no.

you can try with the below command

```
ycsb load cassandra-10 -p hosts="<ip address of the machine>" -p port=9160 -p recordcount=1000000 -P <path of the workload> -s
```